# Как сделать SQL-запрос с условием IF?

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть большой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      p.id, p.groupid, p.postid, p.date, p.likes, p.reposts, p.text, 
      p.att1_type, p.att1_data, p.att2_type, p.att2_data, p.att3_type, 
      p.att3_data, p.att4_type, p.att4_data, p.att5_type, p.att5_data, 
      p.att6_type, p.att6_data, p.att7_type, p.att7_data, p.att8_type, 
      p.att8_data, p.att9_type, p.att9_data, p.att10_type, att10_data, g.rating
    FROM `posts` p
    JOIN `grouplists` g 
        ON p.`groupid` = g.`groupid` 
    WHERE g.`usid` = '$usid' 
        AND p.`reposts` >= g.`reposts` 
        AND p.`likes` >= g.`likes`
                    AND g.`hide` = '0'
    ORDER BY p.date DESC
    LIMIT 40
) AS tmp ORDER BY tmp.`rating` DESC
```

Мне нужно перед `ORDER BY p.$sortMode` добавить что-то вроде:

```
AND p.postid IN (SELECT pid FROM stamps WHERE checkdate-cdate<=g.timeout)
```

Но нужно добавлять эту строку только если `g.timeout` не равно нулю (`0`), иначе нужно нужно ничего не делать. Я что-то пытался придумать как это сделать и с `CASE`, и с `IF()`, но ничего не выходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать.

Comment: ну так и сделайте: `... AND (g.timeout = 0 OR p.postid IN (SELECT pid FROM stamps WHERE checkdate-cdate<=g.timeout))`

Comment: @BOPOH работает, ура! Спасибо большое! Напишите ответ, чтобы я отметил его.

Answer (score 2):

```
checkdate-cdate<= 
  CASE 
    WHEN g.timeout=0 THEN checkdate-cdate 
    ELSE g.timeout 
  END
```